# Neovim diagnostic virtual_text keep on showing only after save current file

Tags: neovim

this is my neovim diagnostic config, I have enabled "update_in_insert"
[image: neovim config]

when diagnostic detect new error, It will show them correctly, but when error is fixed,
it still show the old virtual text even after leave insert mode until save current file,   here you can see, when line 29 is commented, all errors should be gone
[image: my rust code]

Comment: [Please don’t post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/). You can [edit] and use Markdown to insert blocks of code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's a problem about vim diagnostic GUI, I have to show it by image

Comment: I suppose Ben point out the configuration screenshot that could be replaced by the actual excerpts. The second screenshot is very useful indeed.

Comment: Which plugin is creating these warning? Do you still have the warning after you reload the files `:e %`? It looks to me a plugin bug at first glance.

Comment: I'm using AstroNvim, this is its default settings, I only added line 29-31

Comment: I found that "update_in_insert" works well in other conditions, except here that when comment line 29 , virtual text should be gone but not.